# How to loop to assign NA for different column with different threshold

Tags: r

I have a data set with several column, for each column i want to find a threshold value to make the NA count between 1010-1020. Below is the way i tried coding. Here is the example for the data.

```
X1       X2      X3
1.51    0.00    0.00
0.31    3.90    0.00
0.64    13.64   0.00
0.26    9.66    0.00
0.36    0.04    0.00
0.51    0.03    0.00
0.30    0.08    0.02
0.01    0.20    0.04
0.02    0.03    0.00
0.00    0.47    0.00
0.00    1.44    5.54
0.00    2.68    0.74
0.03    0.68    5.49
1.72    0.08    1.54

   threshold=seq(0.5,by=0.1,5)
   for (j in threshold){
      for (i in 1:3){
      data[,i]=ifelse(data[,i]> j,data[,i],NA)
      if((sum(is.na(data[,i]))==range(2,4)) {break
      }
      }}
```

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: You can't test if a value is in a range using `==`. You need to test > min and < max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's how I'd do it.

```
threshold <- rep(NA,50)

for (i in 3:50){

  # Find the number of current NAs
  nNA <- sum(is.na(pred[,i]))

  # Find the 1015th smallest value (minus the number of NAs you already have)
  threshold[i] <- sort(pred[,i])[1015 - nNA]
  pred[pred[,i] < threshold[i],i] <- NA
}
```

Edit: Changed to fit all new requirements.

Comment: thanks you very much i was able to calculate the threshold for each column... I also wanted to use it and update the data pred

Comment: Edited so that thresholds are stored in `threshold` and `pred` is updated. Some things could be done a bit cleaner, but at this point I had to edit it so often that I'll leave the perfection up to you :)